# Using Vinagre With Multiple Computers

Tags: vnc, remote, vinagre

I have got multiple computers that I want to connect to. They're all in my local area network. I don't want to write their IP addresses all the time. I'm looking for an easier way to connect them. Like,

```
vinagre --connect 1
```

Connecting computers by their predefined IDs or something like that.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can edit you `/etc/hosts` and add some name and ip for each pc you will yo connect.

Example

command is:

```
sudo nano /etc/hosts
```

At the end of file add you hosts

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.1.1       xxx.xxx.xxx        xxx

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters

# At the end of file add you local pc's
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx    nice_blond
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx    nice_body
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx    just_nice
```

After this you will can connect to "nice_body"

```
vinagre just_nice
```